# How to Replace Combobox Binding with Button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, itemscontrol

My code generates panels on function call defined in .cs file. There is ItemControl used in code to generates these Panels . Each Panel has it's `Textbox` ,  `Slider` and `Combobox`.

Each Panel's Slider and Combobox is playing with TextBox.Text Like:

1. Slider to increase Textbox.Text Font Size.
2. Combobox to Select alignment of TextBox.Text.

I want to replace Combobox with Button with Content `Left`. So as i click on Button it's Content must change to `Right` and similarly from  `Right` to `Left`., to make changes to `Alignment`.

Can anyone solve my problem? Here Code is:

**XAML FILE:**

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="lstItemsClassM" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <ComboBox x:Name="cboOccupation" IsEditable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Text="{Binding Path=Alignment, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Margin="4" Width="140">
                        <ComboBoxItem>Right</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>Left</ComboBoxItem>

                    </ComboBox>

                    <Button Content="{Binding Alignment, Mode=TwoWay}" Click="Button_Click" Tag="{Binding PKId}" SourceUpdated="Button_SourceUpdated" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtText" Width="300" Height="100" Text="{Binding Text;, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="{Binding FontSize, Mode=OneWay}" TextAlignment="{Binding Alignment, Mode=OneWay}"  />
                    <Slider Minimum="10" Maximum="30" Value="{Binding FontSize, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

**.cs File**

```
 public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    protected ObservableCollection<ClassM> texts = new ObservableCollection<ClassM>();
    int dv;
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dv=1;
        texts.Add(new ClassM() { PKId=dv, Text = "Test 1" });
        dv=2;
        texts.Add(new ClassM() { PKId=dv, Text = "Test 2" });

        lstItemsClassM.ItemsSource = texts;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myValue = ((Button)sender).Tag;
      foreach (var f in texts.ToList())
            {
                if (f.PKId.ToString() == myValue.ToString())
                {
                    f._alignment = "Right";
                    MessageBox.Show(f._alignment);
                }
            }
    }

    private void Button_SourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {
        var myValue = ((Button)sender).Tag;
       foreach (var f in texts.ToList())
        {
            if (f.PKId.ToString() == myValue.ToString())
            {
                f._alignment = "Right";
                MessageBox.Show(f._alignment);
            }
        }
    }


}


public class ClassM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _id;
    private int _pkid;
    private string _text;
    private double _fontSize = 10;
    public bool _isChecked { get; set; }
    public string _alignment="Left";

    public int PKId
    {
        get { return _pkid; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _pkid)
            {
                _pkid = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isChecked)
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _text)
            {
                _text = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public double FontSize
    {
        get { return _fontSize; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _fontSize)
            {
                _fontSize = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public string Alignment
    {
        get { return _alignment; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _alignment)
            {
                _alignment = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The `TextBox.TextAlignment` property is of the enumeration type `System.Windows.TextAlignment`.

If you want to bind it without having to implement your own value converter then you want to populate the ComboBox with the actual enum values, not just a string with the same name like "Left" and "Right"...

Here's how you'd make a ComboBox represent TextAlignment:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <TextAlignment>Left</TextAlignment>
        <TextAlignment>Right</TextAlignment>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

Now you can bind the `SelectedItem` property of the ComboBox to the `TextAlignment` property of the TextBox.

Or in your case if you want to bind both to an underlying data context then you would need to change this:

`private string _alignment = "Left";`

To this:

`private TextAlignment _alignment = TextAlignment.Left;`

Comment: oh you didn't get my question. my Code is working fine i want to do same thing via button rather than Combobox.